# Who built the Republic Star Destroyers?

Tags: star-wars

At the end of *Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones* we see hundreds of already built star destroyers.

Did the Kaminoans build them as well as cloning the troopers or did the Republic source these else where?

Comment: That is a good point... Not just the Star Destroyers, but the fighters, land assault vehicles, weapons, armor\uniforms. The Republic didn't just receive clones... they received a fully assembled army.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Rothana Heavy Engineering](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rothana_Heavy_Engineering), a subsidiary of Kuat Drive Yards, built the Acclamator ships, the LAAT family of gunships and the walkers. Once the Kaminoans had the contract to grow the clone army, they subcontracted to Rothana to build the army's equipment. The Kaminoans themselves designed and built the clone trooper armour, hand weapons such as the DC-15 rifle were supplied by BlasTech.

Comment: I thought the original storm trooper armor was purchased from mandelore.

Comment: @Chad - Mandalore. And it was modeled on Fett' Mandalorian armor but wasn't necessarily built there.

Comment: I know that the quality of the armor circa BoY was degraded when compared with the armor the 501st had at the start of the clone war.  They talked about it in one of the novellas about the surviving clones.  I swore they said the original stuff was beskar.

Comment: Special Ops stuff I think was, but standard-issue was not